# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'marlm'

Tags: python, django

I have to create a view which returns me the posts of a particular owner/author
This error in coming from view bellow. I know this is a simple thing that I am missing. Please help me on this:   (marlm is the ID I created to test)

```
def view_by_owner(request):
    user = request.user.username
    posts_owner = Post.objects.filter(owner=user)
    return render_to_response('view_post.html',{'view_owner':posts_owner})
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    datposted = models.DateTimeField('date posted')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', null=True)

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Logout(User):
    force_logout_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Show your model definitions and the complete error traceback you get. Also, does replacing `request.user.username` with `request.user` help? Thanks.

Comment: Yes Helped...hehe Thank you very much. Learning each day. Can you tell me why the ".username" was causing the fails ?

Comment: I edited the question with models

Comment: Lookup is done by ID (or by object), not by username, that's why.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that owner is a foreign key to User, not the value of the user name. To lookup by that, you will need to span that relationship, like so:

```
posts_owner = Post.objects.filter(owner__user__username=user)
```

Or, more simply, you could do this:

```
posts_owner = Post.objects.filter(owner__user=request.user)
```